# Duplicate/Archive entry in Django to another model

Tags: python, django

I have been at this for Two days and I'm now hoping someone can point me in the right direction. All I am trying to do is duplicate an entry in a table/model into another model with mirrored fields, essentially creating an archived version. I want this to happen when the user calls the update view.

What I have tried so far is setting `pk` to `None` and then trying to find a way to move the previous version to the mirrored/archive model. After a couple of hours of research I gave up on this path. Next I thought the answer would lie with the `pre_save` receiver but I can't find a way to access the model instance to then `save` that to the archive model.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=InstrumentAnnual)
def archive_calc_instance(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    stored_id = getattr(instance, 'id', None)
    e = InstrumentAnnual.objects.filter(id = stored_id)
    archive = InstrumentAnnualArchive(e.field_name, e.another_field_name...)
    archive.save()
```

As far as I can tell this should work however `e` only contains the First field from the model.

Is there something that can be done with this code to achieve my goal or is there a more 'Django' way to solve this? I.e. some sort of official archive feature?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817422/copy-model-object-from-a-model-to-another-in-django

Comment: Thanks Igor, I did see that post yesterday but thought it wasn't what I was looking for. Apparently it was! I've posted my new code below.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @Igor's comment I amended my solution to this:

```
def archive_calc(self, object_id):
    annual = InstrumentAnnual.objects.get(id = object_id)
    annual_archive = InstrumentAnnualArchive()

    for field in annual._meta.fields:
        setattr(annual_archive, field.name, getattr(annual, field.name))
    annual_archive.pk = None
    annual_archive.save()
```

It occured to me that using `pre_save` wouldn't work as it is listening/linked to a model, not a view as I originally thought. So I placed the above code in my Update View and called it passing the `id` in `object_id`.

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using named arguments in your constructor, otherwise the first argument will be interpreted as the `id`, so try:

```
# omitted code
e = InstrumentAnnual.objects.filter(id=stored_id)
archive = InstrumentalAnnualArchive(field_name=e.field_name, another_name=e.another_field_name, …)
archive.save()
```

But you could also use Django's `create` function, so:

```
# omitted code
e = InstrumentAnnual.objects.filter(id=stored_id)
archive = InstrumentalAnnualArchive.objects.create(field_name=e.field_name, another_name=e.another_field_name, …)
```

This way handles the save for you, so you don't need to explicitly save your object.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried the above before trying the code in my answer. It still had the issue of only being able to get the First field in the queryset 'e'.