# Copy Model Object Id From a Model To Another Model In Django

Tags: python, django

I want to copy data from a model to another model, I found an example [Copy Model Object From a Model To Another In Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817422/copy-model-object-from-a-model-to-another-in-django) but I'm getting an error:

> AttributeError: 'BigAutoField' object has no attribute 'wid'.

I want `wid` in the tobjects model to get the `Id` from `w_orders` model. This is my code:

**models.py**

```
class w_orders(models.Model): 
    Id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    datedefwo = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    datesched = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    datefinished = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    sign = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    statusid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    typeid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    navkonsid = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    navname = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navcustadr = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navdebt = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    navpropcode = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navdepcode = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navphoneno = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navreasoncomp = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    nightshift = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    priority = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    stid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    mapurl = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Id

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(w_orders, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        newob = tobjects()
        ...
        newob.save()



class tobjects(models.Model): 
    oid = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    wid = models.ForeignKey(w_orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objtypegisid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    objgisid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condgenid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condriskid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condratsid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condmhcoverid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condmhwallid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipehydrsid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipehydreid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipedepvolsid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipedepvoleid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipedepconssid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipedepconseid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    txt = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.oid
```

Comment: are you using SQL-SERVER ?

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Comment: do you have import BigAutoField in your models ?...

Comment: some thing like this: from sqlserver_ado.fields import BigAutoField

Comment: module not found

Comment: This method works only if both the models have exactly same fields, as mentioned in the link. How many fields do you want to copy ?

Comment: just the Id from model class w_orders to wid in the model class tobjects

Comment: The code you copy-pasted is working on models _instances_, not on model _classes_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class w_orders(models.Model): 
    Id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    datedefwo = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    datesched = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    datefinished = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    sign = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    statusid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    typeid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    navkonsid = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    navname = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navcustadr = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navdebt = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    navpropcode = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navdepcode = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navphoneno = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navreasoncomp = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    nightshift = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    priority = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    stid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    mapurl = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Id




class tobjects(models.Model): 
    oid = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    wid = models.ForeignKey(w_orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objtypegisid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    objgisid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condgenid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condriskid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condratsid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condmhcoverid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condmhwallid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipehydrsid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipehydreid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipedepvolsid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipedepvoleid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipedepconssid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipedepconseid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    txt = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.oid

    @receiver(post_save, sender=w_orders)
    def ensure_order_exists(sender, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('created', False):
            tobjects.objects.get_or_create(wid=kwargs.get('instance'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for o in w_orders.objects.all():
    t = tobjects.create(wid=o)
    t.save()
```

Also possible is bulk_create which is faster but only works with PostgreSQL (please read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):

```
tobjects.objects.bulk_create([tobjects(wid=o) for o in w_orders.objects.all()])
```

Please consider [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for your code. It's horrible to read.

Comment: It doesn't quite work. I created first an w_orders object and the wid took the id of the w_orders but when I deletet the w_orders object and I created another one I got an error:
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "MMS_tobjects" violates foreign key constraint "MMS_objects_wid_id_b67f7eb2_fk_MMS_w_orders_Id"
DETAIL:  Key (wid_id)=(1) is not present in table "MMS_w_orders".

Comment: Is there a reason why you named the field `wid`? For Django ORM it's the `w_order` object itself, not it's id. Your naming is really confusing.

Comment: The field refers to the referenced `w_orders` object not its id. Your name is really confusing. If you create a `tobjects` object you need to provide a `w_orders` object for the ForeignKey field

Comment: If you carefully read the code you will see that whenever a w_order object is created a tobjects object will be created automatically, and wid is a foreignkey related to the w_orders objects so I really dont understand what do you find so confusing in here ?