# How to create a loop for an approval system?

Tags: python, django

I created an approval system for my project. I have several users. These users are analyst, lead, manager, etc. I have a credit limit table (`DoaTable`) in my system. I want to when a `lead` type user updates a field in this table it shouldn't be accepted until a manager approves it.

So, the old value should be valid until the `manager` approves the new values, and when the manager approves it the new value should be accepted.

I created a new model. When a lead wants to update this table, data will save a second model (table) called as `DoaTableBeforeApproval`. In this way, when a manager approved the table which a lead update, DoaTable should be equal to new table (DoaTableBeforeApproval). How can I create a loop for this equality?

**models.py**

```
LIMITS = (
        ('Low Risk', 'Low Risk'),
        ('Medium Risk', 'Medium Risk'),
        ..'),
        ('Strict Credit Check', 'Strict Credit Check'),
        ('No Credit Check', 'No Credit Check'),
    )

RANKS = (
        ('Analyst', 'Analyst'),
        ('Senior Analyst', 'Senior Analyst'),
        ('Lead', 'Lead'),
        ('Manager', 'Manager'),
        ...
    )


class DoaTable(models.Model):

    rank = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=RANKS)
    risk = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=LIMITS)
    limit = models.FloatField()
    comp_name = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


class DoaTableBeforeApproval(models.Model):

    rank = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=RANKS)
    risk = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=LIMITS)
    limit = models.FloatField()
    comp_name = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**views.py**

#This is for the leads

```
def update_limit_before_approval(request, id):
    limiting = get_object_or_404(DoaTableBeforeApproval, id=id)
    form = UpdateDoaTableFormForApproval(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=limiting)
    limiting_item = DoaTable.objects.filter(id=id)

    if form.is_valid():
        update_form = form.save(commit=False)
        update_form.save()
        return redirect('approvals:update_limit_list')

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'limiting_item': limiting_item,
    }

    return render(request, 'limitUpdate.html', context)
```

#This is for the managers

```
def update_limit_by_manager(request):
    limit = get_object_or_404(DoaApprove)
    current_user = request.user
    userP = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=current_user)
    form = DoaTableApproval(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=limit)
    limiting_item = DoaTable.objects.filter(comp_name=userP[0].company)

    doa = DoaTable.objects.filter(comp_name=userP[0].company)
    doa_new = DoaTableBeforeApproval.objects.filter(comp_name=userP[0].company)

    if form.is_valid():
        if form.approved:
              *******************
              **some loops here**
              *for doa = doa_new*
              *******************
        form.save()

        return redirect('approvals:update_limit_list')

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'limiting_item': limiting_item
    }

    return render(request, 'limitApprove.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class DoaTableApproval(forms.ModelForm):
    approved = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        coerce=lambda x: x == 'True',
        choices=((False, 'Disapproved, review again'), (True, 'I confirm')),
        widget=forms.RadioSelect
    )

    class Meta:
        model = DoaApprove
        fields = ('approved',)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either assign all values one by one like below:

```
doa.rank = doa_new.rank
doa.risk = doa_new.risk
doa.limit = doa_new.limit
doa.comp_name = doa_new.comp_name
doa.save()
```

or you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10818948/6309296).